# Black Display on Alienware M17 and very slight/soft clicking sound

Tags: windows, display, nvidia-graphics-card, external-display, clicking-sound

I have an Alienware M17 laptop that I have had for several years.  I was trying to plug an external monitor early today and when I did so, I noticed the monitor was flickering.  So I tried an different HDMI port on the Monitor (there are three so I moved the HDMI cable from port 1 to port 2). I couldn't get the monitor to receive a signal, so I tried the other ports, but then I noticed, the primary monitor on my laptop was black.  I rebooted and unplugged everything attached to my laptop.  I could hear Windows boot up but just a black screen.  I connected a USB to HDMI adapter and I can verify that everything seems to boot normally, but I can't see the bios screen or run any diagnostics in the bios.  I also noticed that hte NVIDIA GeForce GTX 780M driver was not working.  I did a clean install of the driver and rebooted and the driver still isn't working.  I also noticed an every so slight, barely audible clicking noise that sounds like it's coming from the point where the built-in monitor attaches to the body of the laptop.

Any ideas what is causing this?  Is this a hardware failure?  Is there any way to determine if it's hardware related and is this something that I could possibly repair myself, or will I need to send this into Dell for repair?

Thanks!